# Official documentation for all connection string parameters

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, connection-string

I've been hunting for this information for years now but I don't seem to be able to find it:

Is there any documentation available on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com) providing a table with all valid connection string parameters, their valid argument values, their default values and their implications, for SQL Server and LocalDB?

All I find are some tutorials and example pages, but no thorough reference page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Connection string keywords for Microsoft-supplied SQL Server drivers vary by API. The documentation is included with the API-specific driver documentation.

Below are links to the official Microsoft documentation connection string keyword pages for some commonly used drivers. I did not include older and legacy drivers as those should not generally be used for new development.

[System.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) (.NET Framework)

[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-3.0) (.NET Core)

[Microsoft JDBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (MSOLEDBSQL)

[ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-) (ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server)